# Excel Formula - Offset + Index and Match

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, offset

```
=OFFSET(INDEX('File Location]File Name'!$A:$P, MATCH(D915,'File Location]File Name'!$A:$A,0),5),3,0)
```

I have the above code.  However, when I try it, I get #VALUE! unless I open the file that it's indexing.  I have tried "Ctrl + Shift + Enter" on the entire formula but that doesn't work and I get an error message that says the new formula with the curly braces is incorrect when I try to insert them myself.

Is there a way to use Offset + Index, Match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using OFFSET, just add 3 to the Return of the MATCH:

```
INDEX('File Location]File Name'!$A:$P, MATCH(D915,'File Location]File Name'!$A:$A,0)+3,5)
```